# How to encode Algebraic Data Types in current Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, algebraic-data-types, sealed-class

How to encode Algebraic Data Types current in Dart?

Algebraic data types are also known as:

- [Sealed Classes in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html)
- [Algebraic Data Types in Scala](https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/definitions/adt.html)
- [Enums in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/structs.html)
- [Enums with Associated Values in Swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148)
- etc etc.

Question is, how do I implement it in current Dart / Flutter, given that support for it has not landed yet ([see issue #349](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/349))?

There are some approaches explained on the internet, e.g. I've found the `match` library, the `sealed_unions` library, the `if-else` approach, and some more trickier techniques.

But I'd really love some more expert opinions on what to choose, and why did you chose it. Thoughts?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#unionssealed-classes

Comment: This is now something the Dart team is actively building: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/546#issuecomment-1315890650 (The question remains relevant — at least for now — but hopefully that's a useful pointer for some folks coming across it.)